# BrowserSync: Reload HTML on Change

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'm using Gulp + BrowserSync and I'm trying to reload my development website when changes are made to my HTML files, but I can't seem to get it working.

I'm getting no errors in the command line, my page seems to reload but the changes I've made don't appear in the browser, unless I quit the gulp task and run it again.

This is my current setup:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var swig = require('gulp-swig');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;

gulp.task('serve', function () {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: './Build'
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('templates', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/*.html')
    .pipe(swig())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./Build'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['serve', 'templates', 'sass', 'js'], function() {
  gulp.watch('./src/*.html', ['templates']);
  gulp.watch(['./src/scss/*.scss', './src/scss/**/*.scss'], ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('./src/js/*.js', ['js']);
});
```

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The problem in this setup seems to be swig. When you check the files in `./Build`, they haven't changed, so the browser is loading the files correctly. But swig does not get the changes. Disabling swig's caching feature should resolve this:

```
gulp.task('templates', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/*.html')
    .pipe(swig({
      defaults: { cache: false }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./Build'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Comment: This was killing me. Setting cache to false works. Thanks.